# python csv add column values based on another column

Tags: python

I have a two column csv file

```
    row    vote
     1      0
     1      0
     1      1
     2      0
     2      0
     3      1
     3      0
```

I'm trying to write a python script so that each vote is counted depending on the row number, thus outputting

```
   row    vote
    1      1
    2      0
    3      1
```

what I've tried so far with a text file:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split(",")]
        try:
            row = int(tokens[1])
            vote = int(tokens[1])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        d[row] += vote
print d
```

and I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` errors

Comment: could you fix your indentation in code you posted ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `row = int(tokens[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adalee mentioned, you probably should have `row = int(tokens[0])`.

Here is one way to do this:

```
result = {}

with open("test.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(",")

        row = None
        vote = None

        try:
            row = int(tokens[0])
            vote = int(tokens[1])
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        if row is not None:
            if result.has_key(row):
                result[row] += vote
            else:
                result[row] = vote

print result
```

And output could be:

```
{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 9}
```

test.csv file:

```
row,vote
1,0
1,0
1,1
2,2
2,1
3,4
3,2
3,3
```